# Getting search bar to work with Hexo-Algolia

Tags: algolia, hexo

There's some issue with the old algolia account so I've to create a new one, with new App ID and API key etc., for testing with updated contents but now my search-bar wouldn't work.

So what's in the current `_config.yml` file is as followed:

```
algolia:
  en:
    api_key: c3d5d4c995b5e0c2ffb5623900279a66
    index_name: hexo
  zh-cn:
    api_key: cdea7d4e47d84f6145b77e7f68689f35
    index_name: hexo_zh-cn
```

and it's actually working fine with search bar showing. Just that the search-contents are wrong.

So with my new set of ID and API keys, I tried to simply replace the above api_key with the new one and running the `hexo algolia` command, the following error was shown:

```
ERROR [Algolia] Please set a `HEXO_ALGOLIA_INDEXING_KEY` environment variable to enable content indexing.
ERROR >> Read https://npmjs.com/hexo-algolia#api-key for more informations.
```

I followed the documentation for algolia, with the following amendment to the `_config.yml` and the `hexo algolia` command works like a charm:

```
algolia:
  applicationID: CDWIP9PSJ7
  apiKey: 218de3a558ce35814a7ac580345770a5
  indexName: hexo
```

However, **here's come the issue, my original search bar wouldn't appear** anymore :/ I've noticed it's probably due to the missing `en:` & `zh-cn:`, but when I added those in, my `hexo-algolia` command wouldn't work again with the following error:

```
FATAL Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: http://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
AlgoliaSearchError: Please provide an application ID. Usage: algoliasearch(applicationID, apiKey, opts)
```

So now I'm puzzled, **how is the old code able to work without the Application ID?** and comes to the question, **is there a version upgrade to Algolia and therefore an update to the format as well?**

I'm actually more concern on how to get the search bar to appear again but I believe the above question can hopefully lead me to solve the issue. But for those who happen to know, help is greatly appreciated!

I believe the "search-bar with algolia script" connection is related to the `after_footer.swig` file with the following original code:

```
<!-- Algolia -->
{% if config.algolia[page.lang] %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/docsearch.js/1/docsearch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('search-input-wrap').classList.add('on');
docsearch({
  apiKey: '{{ config.algolia[page.lang].api_key }}',
  indexName: '{{ config.algolia[page.lang].index_name }}',
  inputSelector: '#search-input'
});
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Much thanks in advance!